# Unable to connect to a MySQL Second Generation instance from an App Engine application (flexible environment) PHP

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, pdo

I am able to connect to Google Cloud hosted mySQL database from a local sever (using the proxy) but I am not able to do so from Google App Engine. The App Engine instance and Google Cloud mySQL instance are in the same area but I have read this should not be any issue anyway with second generation MySQL.

From the local server I am able to connect and send a simple command to manipulate a database.

When I deploy the code to Google App Engine it fails at the following command:

```
$pdo = new PDO($this->dsn, $this->user, $this->password);
```

Where:

$this-dsn is defined as:

```
mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;unix_socket=/cloudsql/<Project ID>:<Location>:<Instance>;dbname=<Database Name>"
```

User and password are defined and validated as is the Instance Connection Name as I am able to login from the local server and manipulate the mySQL database successfully. The text above inside <> delimiters are descriptions of the values used in the PHP code (replaced to obfuscate sensitive information).

I attempted to catch any exception from this command as follows:

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO($this->dsn, $this->user, $this->password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

Sadly, I do not got any message printed on the web client, simply the general browser exception output. Any tips on how to navigate to the VM being instantiated by Google App Engine to look at syslog or other tips to debug server (Google Cloud) code would also be appreciated.

My app.yaml looks like this:

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: web

beta_settings:
   cloud_sql_instances: "<Project ID>:<Location>:<Instance>"
```

Again, this all works nicely from the local server using the cloud proxy script, but just won't play when deployed to Google Cloud. I followed the php bookshelf tutorial closely and then stripped out much of the code to get this far - always verifying sanity by testing on the local server.

Thank you.

Comment: BTW - I am able to log onto an instance of the VM and I do see a socket created under /cloudsql with proper format. The syslog shows several "GAE" environment variables that look promising. No error message that I can find but I'm not very clear what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the following for the dsn:

```
mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/<Project ID>:<Location>:<Instance>;dbname=<Database Name>
```

Comment: Thank you. I solved the issue a different way. I started over with "standard" App Engine flow and had no trouble connecting to the mySQL server with this version. Thank you